# Data set where one date var precedes a different date var

Tags: sas

I have merged two datasets. One data set has the date a project was submitted and the other has when a project was ended. I want to have a new dataset that has only the projects where the ending date is before the submission date. I'm basically trying to identify where projects are being properly closed out before we submit them for outside reviews. Both date variables are date9. formats.

The data looks something like this (edit: there are no missing dates)

```
Service Submission_date End_date
1       1/1/2010        2/1/2009
2       2/1/2010        12/31/2010
3       5/1/2012        3/1/2010
```

I used a simple where statement but I am not still seeing incorrect dates. I used code like this:

```
data correctsubmission;
set projects;
where end_date < submit_date;
run;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If the `end_date` is missing then it will be less than the `submit_date`.  SAS treats all missing values as less than any actual number.

Comment: None of my dates are missing in this instance

Comment: Is it submission_date or submit_date?  Because you have both in the question.  Also, I recommend testing your code with a date constant substituted for end_date and submit_date separately to check that SAS recognizes each variable correctly (e.g., where end_date < '01JAN2010'd).

Comment: Any warnings or notes in the log output?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your variables actually contain dates.

```
data have;
  input Service Submission_date End_date ;
  informat Submission_date End_date mmddyy.;
  format Submission_date End_date yymmdd10.;
cards;
1       1/1/2010        2/1/2009
2       2/1/2010        12/31/2010
3       5/1/2012        3/1/2010
;
```

They should be numeric variables that contain the number of days since 1960. Preferable with a date format (like DATE, YYMMDD, etc) so that humans can read the displayed value.

Also make sure to account for missing values.

```
data want;
  set have;
  where .Z < end_date < submission_date;
run;
```

Or reverse the test.

```
data want ;
 set have;
 where Submission_date > End_date ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you but there are no missing dates.